# Unable to access website after setting up basic-auth in haproxy

Tags: proxy, kibana, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I am trying to set up basic auth infront of my  kibana service that is running on https. From what I understood from the documentation and additional resources online is that I need to create a list of users with credentials. This I have done. In the frontend section I create 2 ACL's where one of them checks uses http_auth to verify the credentials (or so I am led to believe). I then say to use the correct server if both ACLs requirements are met (IE the correct adress and the correct credentials).

Running a `curl -u admin:terriblePassw0rd https://example.com` I get a 404. I'm super grateful for any pointers or guidelines on what to fix or where to look further.

Thank you for your time.

```
userlist userAuth
    user admin insecure-password terriblePassw0rd

frontend default-frontend-hpp
    bind :80
    http-request redirect location https://example.com code 302 if { hdr_dom(host) -i example.com }

frontend default-frontend-https
    bind :443 ssl crt /path/to/cert/example.pem
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https

    acl auth_check http_auth(userAuth)
    acl example hdr(host) -i example.com
    use_backend example-backend if example auth_check

backend example-backend
    server name IP:port check
```

Comment: The solution I finally found was to move the auth check to the backend.

So it now looks like:

    ``backend example-backend
    acl auth_check http_auth(userAuth)
    http-request auth realm servername unless auth_check
    server name IP:port check`

Answer (score 1):

Since it is `404` instead of `503`, then the basic auth should work.

But you might want to change

```
acl auth_check http_auth(userAuth)
acl example hdr(host) -i example.com
use_backend example-backend if example auth_check
```

to

```
acl auth_check http_auth(userAuth)
http-request deny unless auth_check
acl example hdr(host) -i example.com
use_backend example-backend if example
```

This way, if you did not provide correct user/pass, you got `403` which is better than `503` in first one if auth fails.